# 404 - the requested ressource is not available

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-mvc, tomcat

While trying to do a simple program about the Spring MVC I got always the same error when running http://localhost:8080/project_name/:

```
404 - the requested resource is not available
```

This is the architecutre of the project:

```
src
|    +--com
|            +--memorynotfound
|                +--config
|                    |--ServletInitializer.java
|                    |--WebConfig.java
|                +--controller
|                    |--HomeController.java
|    +--resources
|    +--webapp
|        +--WEB-INF
|            +--views
|                |--index.jsp
```

Here is the files in the package `com.memorynotfound.config`:

> ServletInitializer.java

```
package com.memorynotfound.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

> WebConfig.java

```
package com.memorynotfound.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.memorynotfound")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

Files in the package `com.memorynotfound.controller`:

> HomeController.java

```
package com.memorynotfound.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(ModelMap model){
        System.out.println("This is a test ================>");
        model.addAttribute("message", "Spring MVC Java Configuration Example");
        return "index";
    }

}
```

And finally the Jsp file:

> index.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring MVC Java Configuration Example</title>
</head>
<body>

    ${message}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to put all the `.java' files in the same directory

Comment: In real projects we do not put all files in same package !

Comment: I know, but try it because some times this error is caused by a ComponentScan that is not configured propertly, so if you try it and it work, you will know where is the problem!

Comment: dont u need to specify the mapping for project_name ?

Comment: Perhaps because the mapping is `@RequestMapping("/")`, try `@RequestMapping("/project_name")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by doing :

- right click on the project name and select properties
- Select Deployment assembly
- Add spring and JTL jars

Answer (score 0):

I thought that when you were using Spring MVC without a `web.xml` file, [you needed to supply an implementation of `WebApplicationInitializer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

Without such an initializer, you would still need to provide a `web.xml` file.

Minimally your `WebApplicationInitializer` instance should probably use `setLoadOnStartup(1)` and provide a mapping for the dispatcher.

From the referenced web page above

```
public class MyWebApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet());
        registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        registration.addMapping("/example/*");
    }

}
```

Comment: Note that a `ServletInitializer` is not quite the same as a `WebApplicationInitializer` as the `WebApplicationInitializer` can contain multiple `Servlet`s, each requiring it's own initialization.